# Validar si algún elemento de un Array existe en otro PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

en esta oportunidad tengo el siguiente problema.
Necesito poder validar si algún elemento del `array1` se encuentra en el array2.

```
$perfil = array("300","100");
$perfil_permitidos = array("100","300", "400");

//Valido si algunos de los elemento del array perfil, se encuentre en algunos de los elementos del array $perfil_permitidos

if (in_array($perfil, $perfil_permitidos)) {
    //Si existe
    redirect(base_url()."bienvenidos");

} else {
    //No existe
    redirect(base_url()."error403");

}
```

Pero no me funciona, siempre me dice que no esta.

Comment: In_array no hace eso asi como lo queres hacer. te fijaste en la documentacion? https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la función [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) evalua si un **elemento (valor)** está dentro de un array.

Entonces para no modificar tanto su código, podría iterar los elementos del primer array y preguntar si existe el elemento iterado *($value)* en el `array2`.

Además de tener una variable `$existe`, inicializada en `false`, que indique si existe o no algún elemento en el `array`, si existe cambiamos el valor de la variable `$existe` a `true` y salimos del ciclo con `break`.

Posteriormente, validamos la variable `$existe` para la redirección.

```
$perfil = array("300","100");
$perfil_permitidos = array("100","300", "400");
$existe= false;
foreach ($perfil as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $perfil_permitidos)) {
       //
        $existe = true;
        break;
    } 
}
if($existe) redirect(base_url()."bienvenidos");
else redirect(base_url()."error403");
```

Si desea hacer uso de funciones existentes en PHP directamente, podría utilizar `array_intersect` como se explica en la  respuesta de @anonimo , otra forma sería utilizar [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/array-diff) esta función retornará los valores del primer `array` pasado por parámetro que no están en el segundo `array` pasado por parámetro. *(pueden pasarse más arrays)*

entonces preguntamos, si la cantidad `count()` de lo que retorna dicha función es igual al `count` de `$perfil`, entonces no existirá ningún elemento que se repita.

```
$perfil = array("300","100");
$perfil_permitidos = array("100","300", "400");
if(count(array_diff($perfil, $perfil_permitidos))!=count($perfil) ){
     //Si existe
     redirect(base_url()."bienvenidos");
}
else{
     //No existe
     redirect(base_url()."error403");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

También lo puedes conseguir con el método `array_intersect` para encontrar todas las intersecciones que ocurren entre los elementos de los 2 arreglos quedando así

```
<?php

$perfil = array("300","400");
$perfil_permitidos = array("100","300", "400");

$res = array_intersect($perfil, $perfil_permitidos);

var_dump($res);
```

Dàndote este resultado

> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "300" [1]=> string(3) "400" }

Aqui te dejo la [dcoumentación](https://www.php.net/array_intersect)

Comment: Esto tambien sirve, pero dado que OP no sabia ni usar in_array, creo que habria que agregar que hacer para saber si la respuesta es que hay interseccion o no hay...

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a pruebas que he visto, `in_array` trabaja más rápido que `array_intersect`.

Creo que la propuesta de @DevJoel se puede todavía optimizar un poco más.

Aquí nos vamos a ahorrar la variable booleana `$existe` y también el `if` de la redirección. Se trata de crear una variable `$url` inicializada a `error403`, la cual sólo cambiará a `bienvenidos` cuando la comparación se cumpla. Luego usamos `$url` para redirigir.

```
$perfil = array("300","100");
$perfil_permitidos = array("100","300", "400");
$url= "error403";
foreach ($perfil as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $perfil_permitidos)) {
        $url= "bienvenidos";
        break;
    } 
}
redirect(base_url().$url);
```

Comment: Es un buen detalle, pero no sé si sea una considerable mejora el validar una variable booleana, y hacer directamente la redirección, en escenarios por ejemplo, que se desee hacer algo antes de hacer la re dirección fallaria, igual está bueno.

Comment: @Dev.Joel en el código presentado la intención es simplemente redirigir según la condición dada, por tanto la variable booleana estaría de más en este caso, como también el `if` final. De todos modos, si hay que hacer algo más, se haría dentro del  `if`. Mientras más claro y simple sea el código, mejor.